# React and FireStore - How to find out the total number of documents in a collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

In the following code, I use the **totalDoclNumbers** and a **docLimit** to create a kind of pagination.
If I assign **totalDoclNumbers** a static number, everything works.

But I want that **totalDoclNumbers** is actually the number of all documents in the collection and it should be calculated programatically.
For this I tried the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import DeleteCard from './DeleteCard';

const List = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [beginAfter, setBeginAfter] = useState(0);
  const [totalDoclNumbers, setTotalDoclNumbers] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await db
        .collection('FlashCards')
        .orderBy('customId')
        .limit(docLimit)
        .startAfter(beginAfter)
        .get();
      setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
      setTotalDoclNumbers(docs.length - 1); // Causes ERROR
      // setTotalDoclNumbers(100); // This works
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [beginAfter]);

  const docLimit = 10;

  // Creating a menu for our documents (10 documents per each menu)
  const RenderDocumentMenu = () =>
    Array(totalDoclNumbers / docLimit)
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => {
        const onClick = () => setBeginAfter(docLimit * i);
        return (
          <div key={i} className='document__set' onClick={onClick}>
            {docLimit * i + 1} to {docLimit * i + docLimit} Data
          </div>
        );
      });

  return (
    <>
      <div className='document'>
        <RenderDocumentMenu />
      </div>

      <ul className='list'>
        {cards.map((card) => (
          <li key={card.id} className='list__item'>
            <DeleteCard card={card} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <AddCard />
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```

But then I get this error:  'docs' is not defined  no-undef

The line which causes the problem is this one: **setTotalDoclNumbers(docs.length - 1);**

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: There's no variable named docs, maybe you wanted to type `data.docs.length`?

Comment: Yes, I need to use data.docs.length. However, now I can see that there's a problem with the logic of my code. Because of the .limit() parameter in my query, data.docs.length always shows only the number of documents, which is determined via .limit(). I guess I need to run a second separate query to catch first all available documents in collection and assign it to totalDoclNumbers.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty clear that in your useEffect you need to access the `docs` using `data.docs`.

**Like this**

```js
...
setTotalDoclNumbers(data.docs.length - 1); 
...
```

Just a heads up - The `data.docs` can be an empty array, so in that case, you are doing something like `setTotalDoclNumbers(-1)`. So just watch out.